# Forbidden - When committing with html tags - GOGS

Tags: html, git, okd, gogs

---

hi im using gogs 0.11.34 in OKD 3.11, with DB MySql but when I commit and it contains an html tag, it shows the error of:

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource"

[Forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pZ0u.png)

This error only occurs with html tags

In any file that is committed with an html tag, it shows the error:

1. Original File -> [Original File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCGv7.png)
2. File Modification -> [File Modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lILrg.png)
3. When committing -> [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlQ2M.png)

Comment: Please add a specific example of your full commit command!

Comment: This happens when I am using the browser

Comment: Share the exact commit command! (with the used HTML tag)